# Elastix Hylafax can't exceed 255 virtual devices

Tags: asterisk, tty, fax, elastix

If anyone has noticed, you can not create more than 255 virtual fax devices on Elastix. When you exceed 255, they will no longer work.

I have found where the bug is, but need help figuring out a solution.

What happens is that in `/etc/inittab`, where the `ttyIAX` lines are, the first field which is the `id` starts with `fx` then the number of the device.

i.e:

```
  fx1:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX1
  fx2:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX2
  etc....
```

Now when this reached `ttyIAX` 256, this is what you get:

```
  fx100:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX256
```

And here, the `id` which is `fx100` exceeds 4 characters, and it will no longer work. Also anything after `ttyIAX256`, will not work as well because the id will always be more than 4 characters: `fx101 - fx102 - fx103... etc..` and this field should be 4 characters or less.

Now, I think making this field read more than 4 characters is a bit difficult or can not be achieved, as this is the way the operating system is built.

However, perhaps we can prefix the id with only `f` instead of `fx` and this way we would add a much higher capacity of `ttyIAX` devices that should suite everyone.

If you know where to change this, please advise or recommend a different approach if you have any.

Your time is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I thought I'd post it here for others.

You will need to edit the following file to change the id initialization in the inittab.

```
/usr/share/elastix/privileged/faxconfig
```

Note: There is two occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Identificator doesn't metter.

You can try do

```
fa1:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX1

fa99:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX1

fb1:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX1

fb99:2345:respawn:/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyIAX1
```

But i am afraid inittab not designed to run alot of scripts.

Note, kernel also can have issues becuase of multiple scripts running.

Best solution - use spandsp app_fax.so, but that require rewrite of hylafax.

Comment: That was very helping. However, the thing is that Elastix generates the codes itself, and I want to know where this happens, and edit the generation process so that it generates with valid id's. I am seeking this, and if you have any insight that would be great!

Comment: Elastix is opensource. So check source code or ask expert help you.